# Why is this.state undefined in this simple React component using a contrived use of bind?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a simple React app that I just generated with `create-react-app`, and modified only `App.js` to what you see below. This is an exercise to see if I understand `bind` enough to get results I expect as I toy with it. I'm not getting the expected result: I bind `method` in the class to `obj`, and use an `onClick` on a div to execute this bound `method`. In the method definition, I am calling `this.setState`, and `setState` is defined on `obj`, but I get an error that `this.state` is undefined in the `setState` method definition. **Why?**

---

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

const Button = ({ onClick, quantity }) => <div onClick={onClick} style={{ width: 40 , height: 20}}>{quantity}</div>;

const generateButton = (quantity, onClick) => () => <Button onClick={() => onClick(quantity)} quantity={quantity} />

const obj = {
 state: { count: 1000 }, 
setState: ({ count }) => this.state.count += count
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    }

    this.method = this.method.bind(obj);
  }

  method(count) {
    const newCount = this.state.count + count;
    this.setState({ count: newCount})
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div style={{width: 100, height: 100, fontSize: 50}}>{obj.state.count}</div>
            {generateButton(10, this.method)()}
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image: Error in browser]

Comment: Is there a reason you put the state object outside of your class?

Comment: @JClassic I ran into an unexpected issue using bind with another library (React-Data-Grid), so I built this example just to test my understanding of bind. It's not meant to be anything except to ascertain how bind is working.

Comment: You're using an arrow function which doesn't have its own context, but uses `this` which refers to the parent context here, which isn't defined since at the root of the file.

Comment: Using a `function () {}` expression would "work" but that would be confusing as hell since you named these the same as React's component's api, but it's not and won't trigger the lifecycle of React.

Answer (score 3):

When you use arrow functions, the context is taken from the nearest scope in which the function is defined. In your case, `this` would refer to the module scope.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal variable lookup rules. So while searching for this which is not present in current scope, an arrow function ends up finding the this from its enclosing scope.

If you want the scope to remain relative to the object then use a standard function definition

```
setState: function({ count }) {
  this.state.count += count;
}
```

Comment: Ok, that was an easy miss on my part. I'm going to post a question that is the actual issue I am having and will link here.

Comment: The real-life question that inspired this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56978862/how-does-a-react-method-bound-in-constructor-lose-its-boundedness-in-this-examp